# Is it a good idea to dedicate a page to thank people on a personal website?

Tags: website

I wondered if it is a good idea to dedicate a whole page on a personal website to thank some people who have been useful/important through an academic career.

It would be something similar to what we can see in the "Acknowledgments section" of a PhD thesis or a book for instance but more general.

Comment: Seems kind of odd, but I don't see why not.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1543/

Comment: Here is how I would address this question: What is the purpose/function of your personal website? Does thanking these people help achieving this function? If not, I would suggest you not to put acknowledgment on your website since it increase the signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: @ebo I would say the purpose is to promote my skills and expose my professional profile. Maybe you're right.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to put it as "thank you". I have seen quite some personal websites having a section of "friends" or "people I worked with/people I like to talk to". If you like to work with them, it should be implicitly clear that they were useful or important to you, even if you don't write much more than their names and links to their websites.

Comment: *Erratum: One should of course read "decrease the ratio".* Taking the time to thank them privately is something I would consider. In addition, you can "recommend" them on platform such as LinkedIn, and/or acknowledge them on relevant publications.

Comment: Nice ideas, I will take that into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a strange idea. People will wonder why you have made a page like this when nobody else does. And they might think you are just trying to show what a wonderful and grateful person you are.

If I was you, I would just thank people privately or in the acknowledgements sections of publications. Journal articles can have acknowledgements sections as well.

If you really want to express these thanks in a public and long-lasting way, just write one sentence, or a short paragraph, and put that at the bottom of a page on your website that has your academic biography or some paragraphs about your research interests. Then it won't be in the way, and people will easily be able to ignore it. Make it as short as possible, and write it so that it is interesting (or as interesting as possible) even to people who don't know you or the people you are thanking.